# What does it mean by [Limited run with only 5000 made]?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, british-english

**Full Sentences**

> Also as a bonus, this beautiful postcard of the artwork will be
>   included!! This box set will be a limited run with only 5000 made.

Does it mean that **the box set will only sell for 5000 unit**?

or it mean that, **the first 5000 buyer will get the postcard?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantity limit in the sentence is clearly for the **box set**. Meaning to say, only **5000** units of that set will be **made** (produced), hence making it a **limited run**.

Comment: Effectively, this means that only the first 5000 buyers will get the box set. But I think this is more of a marketing gimmick than anything, designed to make people feel like their time is limited to obtain something very special.